# How to plot a bar chart without aggregation Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How do you plot a bar chart without aggregation? I have two columns, one contains values and the other is categorical, but I want to plot each row individually, without aggregation.

By default, `sns.barplot(x = "col1", y = "col2", data = df)` will aggregate by taking the mean of the values for each category in `col1`.

How do I simply just plot a bar for each row in my dataframe with no aggregation?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you want to plot `col2` against `col1`, how do you handle repeated labels in `col1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `'col1'` only contains unique labels, you immediately get your result with `sns.barplot(x='col1', y='col2', data=df)`. In case there are repeated labels, you can use the index as `x` and afterwards change the ticks:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ababab'), 'col2': np.random.randint(10, 20, 6)})
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.index, y='col2', data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['col1'])
ax.set_xlabel('col1')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Similarly, a horizontal bar chart could be created as:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ababab'), 'col2': np.random.randint(10, 20, 6)})
ax = sns.barplot(x='col2', y=df.index, data=df, orient='h')
ax.set_yticklabels(df['col1'])
ax.set_ylabel('col1')
```

Comment: for whatever reason, this isn't working with a horizontal bar chart? If I set ```y = df.index ```and ```x = "col2"```, the figure is simply blank?

Comment: If both axes are numerical, seaborn doesn't know the orientation, but you can set it explicitly with `orient='h'`